# What controls the device name in /proc/mounts?

Tags: kernel, mount, proc

In `/proc/mounts`, my system used to show `/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt` as `/`. After used for some days, including kernel and software upgrading, the line changed to `/dev/dm-0` as `/`. What happened? I booted into the old kernel and it was still `/dev/dm-0`.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal when you are using a multipath device.  Each multipath device has a [World Wide Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) (WWID), which is guaranteed to be globally unique and unchanging. By default, the name of a multipath device is set to its WWID. Alternately, you can set the **user_friendly_names** option in the multipath configuration file, which causes DM-Multipath to use a node-unique alias of the form mpathn as the name. For example, a node with two HBAs attached to a storage controller with two ports via a single unzoned FC switch sees four devices: `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, and `/dev/sdd`.

DM-Multipath creates a single device with a unique WWID that reroutes I/O to those four underlying devices according to the multipath configuration. When the `user_friendly_names` configuration option is set to yes in `/etc/multipath.conf`, the name of the multipath device is set to mpathn. When new devices are brought under the control of DM-Multipath, the new devices may be seen in two different places under the /dev directory: `/dev/mapper/mpathn` and `/dev/dm-n`.

- The devices in `/dev/mapper` are created early in the boot process.
  Use these devices to access the multipathed devices, for example when
  creating logical volumes.
- Any devices of the form `/dev/dm-n` are for internal use only and
  should never be used.

You can also set the name of a multipath device to a name of your choosing by using the alias option in the multipaths section of the multipath configuration file.

For more information see this [The DM-Multipath Configuration File](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/multipath-dm-multipath-config-file.html)

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. I do not have multipath related packages installed. And I do not have /etc/multipath.conf, either. I also blacklisted dm_multipath.ko. So why the internal mount point changed?

Comment: Another point is that, as you said sda1_crypt is created early, is it earlier than dm-0? I see sda1_crypt is just a link to dm-0.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: It is Trusty. Everything updated to latest and the new kernel is 4.3.2, old one is 4.3.0.

Comment: I may have found the reason. Some changes in 4.3 on BTRFS made the difference. I mean by my testing, only BTRFS + 4.3 kernel changed from `/dev/mapper/something` to `/dev/dm-x`.